# Excel file import into SQL

Tags: sql-server, excel

I see people who try to import an Excel and getting this ERORR:

> MSSQL Server Data Import i.e. SSIS package The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 provider is not registered on the local machine. (System.Data)

I got a solution which bypass the problem: try open the Excel you want and save it as worksheet 2003, then try import it from the SQL.

Comment: That does not appear to be a question? Its appears to be an answer, in which case please find where you saw someone ask this and add it as an answer. Leaving it as a question will result in it being closed.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this approach anyway. If your .xlsx file has more than 65,536 rows as you will lose data when you save as 2003 (as the UK Government found out last year when they lost 16k covid cases during import due to saving csv Files as .xls). Just install the correct driver.